# Closing Thunderbird to messaging menu

Tags: thunderbird, messaging-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I hide Thunderbird from the launcher while running?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68640/how-do-i-hide-thunderbird-from-the-launcher-while-running)

I would like to switch to using thunderbird to read my email. However, I can not work out a way to minimise/close thunderbird to the messaging menu (thus avoiding having it cluttering up the unity panel. I have tried using extensions such as firetray, but in Oneiric none of these produce satisfactory results. Any Suggestions?