# Thunderbird 8 with new mail notification

Tags: 10.10, gnome, thunderbird, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I hide Thunderbird from the launcher while running?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68640/how-do-i-hide-thunderbird-from-the-launcher-while-running)

I use ubuntu 10.10 with thunderbird 8. I tried couple of add-ons for email notification but none of them worked. I just want this simple feature like in outlook: [http://i.imgur.com/o6lrw.png](https://i.imgur.com/o6lrw.png)

Note: Yes, also suggestion of a working minimize-to-tray add-on would be appreciated.