# Minimize Thunderbird to Tray

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I hide Thunderbird from the launcher while running?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68640/how-do-i-hide-thunderbird-from-the-launcher-while-running)

I have tried to look for this answer in other questions but there is none that can solve the problem.

What I need is this basic steps. Start Thunderbird and if I want to close it, it minimizes to the system tray (and does not show in the Launcher to avoid having an additional option there). If a new mail arrives, it notifies me via the notify-send popups (Even will minimized) and the New mails appear on the system tray of the email option. When I click this new mails they open thunderbird and show me the new mails.

[image]

When I mention minimized I mean in this panel.

All the other questions regarding Thunderbird minimized are not working.

**UPDATE**: Already tried the Thunderbird Plugin **FireTray**. The problem with it (at least in 12.04 for what I am seeing) is that it minimizes Thunderbird forever. You can only see it again if I click on the system tray menu option "Compose New Message" or "Contacts" (Does not work if I click on "Mail" option). The only option activated with this plugin is to minimize the window when I click on close.

If I remove the Firetray addon after testing for example 5 times and then restart Thunderbird, Thunderbird will open the amount of tries I did. This time it opened 5 Thunderbird. Something like FireTray was holding down Thunderbird from appearing for each time I tried to open it. So in this particular case Firetray is not working or helping, it just minimizes Thunderbird but then creates additional problems for it.