# Thunderbird CPU usage

Tags: thunderbird, cpu-load

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Thunderbird pegging a core at 100%?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158171/why-is-thunderbird-pegging-a-core-at-100)

Is there any reason that Thunderbird uses 18-30% of my CPU constantly. This normally wouldn't be a problem but I like to leave it open so I am notified about my emails and this means the processor in my laptop (Core2Duo 2.0Ghz) doesn't seem to clock down making my laptop get marginally warm and also reducing battery life.

If anyone knows the reason for this or how to stop it please let me know!

P.S. This only occurs when I leave the Thunderbird Windows open, but why?

Comment: You can use mail notification indicators like ["Popper"](http://askubuntu.com/q/130220/37006) and only open your Thunderbird when new mail arrives.

Comment: I noticed that a while ago too. I wrote a perl script to `cpulimit` thunderbird when the screensaver kicks in. http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/ and the script is at http://wirespeed.xs4all.nl/mediawiki/index.php/PC_energy_savings#CPUsaver

Comment: Thanks for that @BasharatSial but how do I know if I've completely closed Thunderbird or just minimized it to the mail applet?

Comment: @RossFleming Thunderbird doesn't get minimised to panel automatically until you're using some add-on to do that. So closing Thunderbird will close it completely. To be sure about it you can check the system monitor for running processes and see if Thunderbird is there?

Comment: There's no legitimate reason for Thunderbird to persistently hover at %20 CPU usage as it does.