# Why is Thunderbird pegging a core at 100%?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, thunderbird, cpu-load

I have experienced 2-3 unexplained lockup over last 10 days.

Today, I had a random lockup (no mouse, keyboard response, 100% CPU).  But, when I finally switched (Ctrl-Alt-F1) to command line (it took several minutes) it told me that **thunderbird-bin** had locked a CPU.

I ran this to resolve:

```
pidof thunderbird-bin
sudo kill ####
```

However, after saving other work, I tried restarting Thunderbird. It went to 90%+ CPU, and within 20 seconds it locked again.

Once I have more detail I will raise a bug (on Ubuntu Forums).

***Does anyone have any other suggestions, advice?***

**UPDATE:** (Sep-2012)

**Thunderbird 13.0.1** is quite stable in safe mode.  *Still working to resolve ..*

---

**UPDATE 2:** (Jan-2013)

Now running Thunderbird 17.0.2 (Ubuntu 12.04).

Still have **ALL** *Plugins* disabled. Works well, and does everything I need.

*Not attempting to resolve.*

Comment: May be same issue as: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12063541

Comment: Maybe related to: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=787348

Comment: *Not sure.*  With **Plugins** mostly disabled (which I don't use anyway) it is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 4):

Change the configuration key

> mail.db.idle_limit

to

> 30000000

In Preferences->Advanced->General->Config-editor

Source: http://rainbow.chard.org/2013/02/19/thunderbird-high-cpu/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried hiding the status bar? ( View->Toolbar->Status bar ) For me it seems that the animated progress bar uses vast amounts of CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that also works is to

```
unset LC_ALL
```

before you launch thunderbird. Previously, I've set mine to "C" to convert the times to a 24H format, but it seems to have quite some performance overhead.