# Thunderbird looses menu in the panel

Tags: unity, thunderbird, appmenu

I have installed the add-ons MinimizedToTray revived 1.0.1 to Thunderbird, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68640/how-do-i-hide-thunderbird-from-the-launcher-while-running). Even though the main functionality of hiding TBird to the tray works well, after a while (minutes) on maximizing it, the menus of TBird are gone form the unity panel. So I have no File/Edit/View ... etc menus. That kills the joy of minimizing it to the tray a bit.

Is there a problem between this add-on and Unity on 12.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That extension is incompatible with the Global Menu Bar Integration. You could disable the later extension as a workaround, to use Thunderbird's native menu.

Comment: so then, if that add-on is incompatible with the Global Menu Bar, is there another possibility to minimize thunderbird to tray?

Comment: Not yet. There is another extension to do this (FireTray), but it has other incompatibilities with Unity. The good news is that this bug will be fixed for Thunderbird 14 (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/775080/comments/15).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This definitely answers my question then. So I'l accept your answer.