# Thunderbird notification on KDE system tray

Tags: kde, thunderbird, email, notification

Is there any way to have Thunderbird notification on KDE system tray.
by Running it in Ubuntu, it doesn't bring any icon in KDE system tray.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 with KDE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I hide Thunderbird from the launcher while running?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68640/how-do-i-hide-thunderbird-from-the-launcher-while-running)

Answer (score 4):

[image: BirdTrayImage]
You can search for **BirdTray** from the Discover store:

However, after you install it there is a bit of setup involved to select all the mailboxes that you want to be notified for. Once you run the program, I suggest that you do that by right clicking on the tray icon and then clicking 'Settings...'. I don't remember all the steps after that but I am happy to update this answer based on your response.

It is a bit clunky because you have to be running both Thunderbird and BirdTray which are two separate programs. But it does the job for me for now.

Tested on Kubuntu 20.04.

P.S. Here is Thunderbird's [open development ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1634907) for that feature.

Answer (score 1):

[edit: those extensions are outdated and no longer supported; thanks for the comment!]

Thanks to an active community there are addons for everything ;)
There is simply an addon for Thunderbird called [FireTray](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/thunderbird/addon/firetray/) which does exactly that. Also if you want to use native KDE notifications you can use [GNotifier](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/thunderbird/addon/gnotifier/).

Comment: those are outdated and no longer supported.